# mongodb-charts ssl data source PRIVATE KEY error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-charts

I'm trying to connect to an SSL protected Mongo DB instance running a service from a local MongoDB-charts deployment. I got a local Mongo running as metadata DB, and MongoDB-charts running from a local container following instructions on:

https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/19.12/installation/

But when I want to connect to a Mongo DB instance running a service and protected with SSL using a certificate I get the following error:

[image: mongodbcharts-error]

I've copied the certificate within the container. I know it is being picked up because If I rename the filename, MongoDB-charts complains that the cert file doesn't exist.

I'm able to connect to the MongoDB service from Mongo shell, and from MongoDB-compass using the same credentials and same certificate, therefore that information is correct. I figure it has to be something missing on the container but I cannot find a solution.

¿Any tips?

Comment: What is the URI you are using? Can't see it.

Comment: mongodb://user:password@host0,host2/dbname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset?ssl=true&sslclientcertificatekeyfile=/mongodb-charts/volumes/db-certs/cert.pem

Comment: `sslclientcertificatekeyfile` is not a standardized uri option name, where did it come from?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/current/administration/configure-ssl-data-sources/#id3

Comment: I see. And what is the text of the error?

Comment: only what is shown on the image "error connecting to MongoDB: failed to find PRIVATE KEY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was provided with the solution in my company internal forum.

I had that error ...

> "Because it’s a CA file, not a Key file - with the option you’re
>   selecting, it’s looking for a certificate and a key"

**Solution**: Use `tlsCAFile` instead of `sslclientcertificatekeyfile` in the Mongo URI.
Example:

```
mongodb://user:password@host0,host2/dbname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset&ssl=true&sslclientcertificatekeyfile=/mongodb-charts/volumes/db-certs/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Charts uses the Go driver - you can see the code that produces that error at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/mongo/options/clientoptions.go.

Since you're using an SSL client certificate, it's expecting to find a private key in the PEM file. Do you have that? A PEM file may contain just a public key, or a public key + a private key. The error implies your file only contains the public key.

Tom

Comment: I will look into that. It's worth mentioning however that I use the same PEM to connect via mongo shell, mongodb compass, and moongose. It would be odd that the file should be modified to be used with charts. I'll check it anyway, thanks for the feedback.